# $X$ is a random variable - show that $P\left(X>n+E(X)\right) \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> $X$ is a random variable with $P(X>0)=1$ and $Var(X)=1$. For all $n
> \geq 1$ show that $P\left(X>n+E(X)\right) \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$

This looks very much like Chebyshev's inequality which is 
$$P\left(\mid X-E(X) \mid \geq a\right) \leq \frac{Var(X)}{a^2} \,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ for } a>0$$

I have tried to work with other inequalities known from Chebychev on Wikipedia for this reason but I didn't come to an end with them.

Instead I have tried this:

$$P(X>n+E(X)) \leq \frac{1}{n^2} \Leftrightarrow P(X>n) \leq \frac{1}{n^2} -E(X) \Leftrightarrow P(X>0) \leq \frac{1}{n^2}-E(X)-n \Leftrightarrow $$  $$ \Leftrightarrow 1 \leq \frac{1}{n^2}-E(X)-n \Leftrightarrow 1 \leq n^2 -\frac{1}{E(X)} -\frac{1}{n} \Leftrightarrow 0 \leq n^2-\frac{1}{E(X)} -\frac{1}{n} -1$$

And now argue that $n^2$ will be greater than the other things on the right side and thus at least zero?

I think this is entirely wrong but I didn't know another way to go hmm..? :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply notice that
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}(X - \mathbb{E}(X) > n) \leq \mathbb{P}(\vert X - \mathbb{E}(X) \vert > n)
\end{equation*}
and now you can use Chebyshev's to get the upper bound $\frac{\text{Var}(X)}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean I can say that $$P(X>n+E(X)) = P(X-E(X) > n) \text{ ? }$$ Because that was also something I wasn't quite sure if that's right / allowed ?

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to transform the expression **inside** the probability.

Comment: Ohh ok one last question I have! Let's say we have $$P(X>n+E(X))= z$$ Could I then say that $$P(X>n) = z-E(X) \text{ ? }$$

Comment: No, this is not true in general. When $\mathbb{E}(X) > z$ then $z - \mathbb{E}(X)$ could be negative, and so it does not make sense to have negative probability.